# How to implement asynchronous loading for responsiveslides.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image-processing

I have a JQuery SLider in my mobile website for an image carrousel . Some times the carrousel have images more than 30 . So even after compressing the images the total weight of the page is getting more than 1150 kb , According to some website for mobile designing

The page weight should not increase more than 500 kb for fast rendering .

I have implemented a simple Asynchronous script for other pages where the image gets loaded only if it is on the viewport . I am not getting how to implement that in responsiveslides Script

Here is the code for responsive slide.min.js 
[**LinkToFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UvL7N/14/)

```
$("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    startidx: 0,
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    maxwidth: 540,
    namespace: "transparent-btns"
});
imageHandler();
//$('.transparent-btns_nav').trigger('click');
$(document).on('click', '.transparent-btns_nav', function (event) {
    imageHandler();
});
```

And the lazyLoader Code is here

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#outerPage',function(){
$.fn.is_on_screen = function () {
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};
CheckIt();

function CheckIt() {
    $('.target').each(function () {
        if ($(this).length > 0) { // if target element exists in DOM
            //alert($(this).is_on_screen());
            if ($(this).is_on_screen()) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
                if ($(this).find('img').attr('data-src')) {
                    var source = $(this).find('img').attr('data-src');

                    $(this).find('img').attr('src', source);


                }
                // log info     
            } 
        }
    });
```

I tried applying the script here but all the images they just dont show when I add data-src instead of src

Any help would be really helpful

Comment: you have all the images in the html ie (src="http://images01...) etc so naturally they will load all at once. Either create a script that dynamically injects 3 or 4 Pics at a time or find a plugging simillar to the one you are using that lazy loads pics